# Is there a convenient way to diff two strings in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, npm, homebrew

Was thinking about creating a homebrew formula or npm package or something to diff two strings in bash, simplifying

```
diff <(echo "string 1") <(echo "string 2")
```

to

```
strdiff "string 1" "string 2"
```

So I'm curious if something like this already exists or nah?

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like

```
   if [ "string1" = "string2" ]; then
```

or just

```
   test "string1" = "string2" && echo equal
```

Do not use

```
   test $a = $b && echo equal
```

the vars can have spaces or other strange things.

Use quotes:

```
   test "$a" = "$b" && echo equal
```

I prefer the explicit test above the also valid syntax

```
[[ "$a" = "$b" ]] && echo ok
```